# File print feedback from Windows

Tags: delphi

I am trying to print several PDF files using some Pdf reader launched using shellExecute in Delphi 2007.

Reliability of such an approach may not be very good because the actual printing can fail due to several reasons. I am wondering if there is a way for my program to know if or when the file is actually send to the print spooler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To monitor printer jobs, you can use the [`FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162722%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API call with `PRINTER_CHANGE_WRITE_JOB` passed in the `fdwFilter` parameter. This will let you know every time job data was written to the printer via [`FindNextPrinterChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

When you're done, don't forget to call [`FindClosePrinterChangeNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162721%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to close all the handles and clean up.

The use can get rather complicated. Dr. Peter Below of [TeamB](http://www.teamb.com) posted a unit that has wrappers around this a while back to the old Borland Code Central pages (which are now available at the Embarcadero site) in a unit called `PBPrintersMonitorU.pas`. You can find it [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/20307), if you have an [EDN](http://edn.embarcadero.com) (Embarcadero Developers Network) account.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I can confirm the success by looking at the Status jsCompleted. Thank you!